# Notation for a "conditional" set

Tags: notation

Is there any commonly used short notation for the following?

$A_n = 
\begin{cases}
\{a_n\},  & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
\emptyset, & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}
$

I'm looking for something like 
$A_n = \{a_n\}_{[\text{$n$ is odd}]}$ that will fit on one row.

Comment: It looks like your sets $A_n$ contain either zero elements or one element, depending on whether $n$ is even or odd. Is that right?

Comment: in this particular case, yes, although it would be interesting to see notation for every $B$, like $A = B_{condition}$

Answer (score 1):

If you use the indicator function (that I note $1_A$) then you can write it
$$
a_n 1_{2\nmid n}\ \ \ \  \ \  a_n 1_{ 2\Bbb Z+1}(n)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a Kronecker delta/indicator function. But "0" would have to be interpreted set theoretically to be $\{\}$.